# Difficulty when saving android file in sqlserver database

Tags: java, android, sql, asp.net

I am having a problem finding the right encoding for a file that is saved to the database through FileUpload from asp.net on sql server 2008 with type Image. I need to migrate a web system to an Android application using a webservice in asp.net for communication with this sql server database, but the saved format is not corresponding with the already saved files. I am not understanding whether it is a question of encoding (ASCII, UTF-8, ...) or problem with base64 encode and decode, or whether it would be more appropriate to treat the file as hexadecimal.

The file is read by the system through the fileupload component:
`file.ARCHIVE = FileUpload1.FileBytes` and then has the save: `context.SaveChanges ()`

the type expected by the database is Image and the web system reads the file normally after saving.

I need to do the same process through a native Android application (java), so I read the file, convert it to base64 to send it to the webservice that does the decode of the file and saves it in the same type in the database. When I compare the string of the file the string is different, so the web system understands the file to be corrupted, even though the application reads normally.

I already tested `command.Parameters.Add ("@ ARCHIVE", SqlDbType.Image) .Value = bytes;` to save, but it seems to me that before this save the file format is no longer the same as the web system.

On Java Android we do like this

```
InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(filename);
            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
```

Comment: Well show your android code. Please tell amount of bytes of file, base64 string on Android and base64 string on server.

Comment: Edited to add this